# RBAC in YII2: user->can() in PHPManager

Tags: php, yii2, rbac

I am trying to configure rbac with phpmanager in my project using the Yii2 advance app version. But \Yii::$app->user->can is not returning the expected.

I wrote the RbacController and executed sucessfully `yii rbac/init`

That updated common/components/items.php as shown

```
<?php
return [
    'user' =>    [ 'type' => 1, 'children'    => [ 'createX', ], ],
    'createX' => [ 'type' => 2, 'description' => 'create a X',],
    'admin' =>   [ 'type' => 1, 'children'    => [  'updateX', ], ],
    'updateX =>  [ 'type' => 2, 'description' => 'update a X', ],
];
```

In SignupForm::signup, I added it:

```
$auth = Yii::$app->authManager;
$roleObj  = $auth->getRole('user'); // this role is defined by the RBAC Controller's init action
$auth->assign($roleObj, $user->getId());
```

assignments.php

```
return [ 2 => [ 'user', ], ];
```

I think that 2 corresponds to the user id.

rules.php

```
return [];
```

common/main.php

```
...
'components' => [
        ...
        'authManager' => [
            'class' => 'yii\rbac\PhpManager',
            'defaultRoles' => ['user','admin'], 
            'itemFile' => '@common/components/rbac/items.php',
            'assignmentFile' => '@common/components/rbac/assignments.php',
            'ruleFile' => '@common/components/rbac/rules.php'
        ],
    ],
...
```

When I got that role permissions, it prints:

Array ( [createX] => yii\rbac\Permission Object ( [type] => 2 [name] => createX [description] => create a X [ruleName] => [data] => [createdAt] => 1438601819 [updatedAt] => 1438601819 ) )

So I'm expecting that user doesn't have updating permission, but in the method XController::update

```
echo \Yii::$app->user->can('updateX'); 
// returns 1, just the same than \Yii::$app->user->can('createX') returning
```

Please some help

Answer (score 0):

First items file should be:

```
<?php
return [
        'user' =>    [ 'type' => 1, 'children'    => [ 'createX', ], ],
        'createX' => [ 'type' => 2, 'description' => [ 'create a X', ], ],
        'admin' =>   [ 'type' => 1, 'children'    => [  'updateX', ], ],
        'updateX' =>  [ 'type' => 2, 'description' => ['update a X', ], ],
];
```

You can verify if the code is fine with var_dump:

```
var_dump(\Yii::$app->authManager);
```